# Finding relative row and column number of a range OR Cell

Tags: vba, excel

Is it possible to find the relative row and column number of a range or cell within a Range.

Example:
In the following Table (Table Name "Table2")
[image: Example Table Data]

If I use the Find method and print the address like so:

```
Dim loHeaderRow As Range
Set loHeaderRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").ListObjects("Table2").HeaderRowRange
Dim rFindResult As Range
Set rFindResult = loHeaderRow.Find(What:="MajorVersion", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

MsgBox rFindResult.Address
```

will Print

```
$C$3
```

But the relative location of the range rFindResult with in the parent range loHeaderRow is:

```
Row number: 1
Column Number: 2
```

Can this be achieved? Especially so by using standard object properties/methods without needing a long set of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Row number will always be `1` as you are finding the text in the header row. As for the Column, you can use `Debug.Print (rFindResult.Column - loHeaderRow.Column) + 1`

For example

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim loHeaderRow As Range, rFindResult As Range

    Set loHeaderRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").ListObjects("Table2").HeaderRowRange

    Set rFindResult = loHeaderRow.Find(What:="MajorVersion", _
                                       LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                       LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                       MatchCase:=False, _
                                       SearchFormat:=False)

    MsgBox "The Row is 1 and the Column is " & _
    (rFindResult.Column - loHeaderRow.Column) + 1
End Sub
```

This will give you `1` and `2` as the row and the column number.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub test2()
    Dim mytable As ListObject
    Set mytable = Sheet1.ListObjects("Table2") '~~> adjust the sheet code name to suit
    Dim myarr: myarr = mytable.Range

    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim mysrch As String

    mysrch = "MajorVersion"
    For i = LBound(myarr, 1) To UBound(myarr, 1)
        For j = LBound(myarr, 2) To UBound(myarr, 2)
            If myarr(i, j) = mysrch Then
                Debug.Print "Relative Row: " & i
                Debug.Print "Relative Column: " & j
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

But if you only need what Sid pointed out in comments, take his route.
Btw, this is just the logic, you can change this into a *function* if you are to use those row and column numbers.